# What insect is this on the photos?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

What insect is this on these photos?
Found in Russia in the living room.

[image: Unknown insect]
[image: Unknown insect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it. It can be Lacewings:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysopidae

Comment: Yes, it look like a lacewing. Many species in Chrysopidae overwinter as adults, and these are often found indoors in the autumn where they are looking for overwintering sites.

Comment: And given the state of genus-group classification of the family (for a slightly dated worldwide system see [here](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/127742#page/3/mode/1up)) that's as far as anyone can go on the available evidence.